# Why does return change my value?

Tags: c++, loops, return

I am writing a function that should return Hello world!, but it returns Hello Wo.. I added a cout right before my return statement to check the value and it is correct.

I pass two parameters into the function, one and two, and my function combines the word and returns. I wrote a loop to transfer one into a new char so the original passed value isn't effected since I am accessing it's array.

Function:

```
char* myStrCat(char inputOne[], char inputTwo[]){
    int sizeOne = myStrLen(inputOne);
    int sizeTwo = myStrLen(inputTwo);
    char functionTemp[100];

    for(int tempReplace = 0; tempReplace < sizeOne; tempReplace++){
        functionTemp[tempReplace] = inputOne[tempReplace];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeTwo; i++){
        functionTemp[i + sizeOne] = inputTwo[i];
    } 
    cout << "check: " << functionTemp << endl;
    return functionTemp;
}
```

Comment: @kiner_shah nothing changed

Comment: You really should use (and return) some [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Answer (score 4):

`functionTemp` is a local variable and `myStrCat()` *returns address of local variable, read the compiler warning*.

Instead of taking `functionTemp` as a local static array take `functionTemp` as `pointer` and allocate memory dynamically using `new` for `pointer` and returns the pointer.

**Edit :**

```
char* myStrCat(char inputOne[], char inputTwo[]){
        int sizeOne = strlen(inputOne);
        int sizeTwo = strlen(inputTwo);
        int bytes = sizeOne + sizeTwo;
        char *functionTemp = new char [bytes + 1];/* allocating memory dynamically for functionTemp */


            for(int tempReplace = 0; tempReplace < sizeOne; tempReplace++){
                    functionTemp[tempReplace] = inputOne[tempReplace];
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < sizeTwo; i++){
                    functionTemp[i + sizeOne] = inputTwo[i];
            }
            cout << "check: " << functionTemp << endl;
            return functionTemp;
    }
```

And in calling function once you got the concatenated string/dynamic address, free it using `delete` to avoid memory leakage. A simple calling function looks like

```
int main() {
        char *temp = NULL;
        temp = myStrCat("Stack","overflow");/* temp holds dynamic address */
        cout<<temp<<endl;
        /* free the dynamically allocated memory */
        delete [] temp ;

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry, I am confused. Could you show me an exmaple

Comment: @Vincent I modified above.